# how to convert string to a double array?

Tags: java, android

i have made a method called simpleDescriptive to calculate a values inside a double array. now the issue is that before i used to get my data from the editText field Using "parseInt /parsedouble(field.getTex().toString());" but now the problem is  how to get my inserted double/int array values from the editText and display is to some where? [this is the code which i have sniped from my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRIX7.png)

[image]

Comment: You should add your code here in your post. Use _code_ to add your code so community can help more. Adding code as an image link is not a good way to get help.

Comment: It looks like you've already got that - `mdisplaytext.getText.toString` should give you the text on the display. Is the issue that you need to split that string up into a bunch of doubles? I believe java has string split methods that can split on spaces.

Comment: sand sorry it was my first time to post my question here

Answer (score 0):

Your myArray is not an array.

Assuming your user enters a series of numbers separated by spaces, you can do:

Replace:

```
double myArray = Double.parseDouble(mdiPlayText.getText().toString());
```

by:

```
String[] numbers = mdiPlayText.getText().toString().split(" ");
        double[] myArray = new double[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i <numbers.length ; i++) {
            myArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]);
        }
```

... and of course error checking etc.

Comment: Happy to hear that. It would be great if you could accept my answer.